# Why are SSH commands not working?

Tags: ssh, dd-wrt

I am using SSH (smarTTY port 22) to access a Netgear R8000 with DD-WRT installed but I keep getting the same error when trying to run any commands.

The error is: *sh: bash: not found*

[image: screenshot]

Also, how does one list file directory for config. I have tried using /etc..

Comment: Does `echo hello` work?

Comment: No it does not work.Welcome to Smart Terminal.
root@192.168.10.1:~# echo hello
sh: bash: not found
root@192.168.10.1:~#

Comment: Find something like "shell" in settings? Something like [this](https://sysprogs.com/w/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/06-smart.png).

Comment: My settings are exactly the same as the one you provided in the link i.e. default shell for background commands = bash

Comment: Then what if you change it to `sh`?

Comment: Wow that worked I think! I changed it from bash to sh and typed in echo hello and got a response "BusyBox v1.25.1 () built in shell (ash)"

Comment: Could you tell me why it needed to be changed to sh instead of bash? I am accessing it through a windows machine.

Comment: How did you change from 'sh' to 'bash'? Presumably with `chsh -s /bin/sh`?

Comment: @MechtEngineer I don’t think OP changed the login shell. From online tutorials about SmarTTY, I guess SmarTTY forces use of certain shell, ignoring the login shell in remote machine. Changing configuration of SmarTTY seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the default shell in SmarTTY from `bash` to `sh` seems to solve the problem. This is possibly a bad design of SmarTTY: it should by default respect to remote user setting, instead of calling `bash` regardless. Some platform, a router in OP’s case, doesn’t have enough space to provide a Bash. On those platforms, user's log-in shell is `sh`, and when the user SSH into it, a decent SSH client (such as OpenSSH) would ask the daemon to start a log-in shell.

Note: this behavior is SSH specific. It doesn’t matter you’re on Windows or Linux.